# Singletons with constructor arguments

Tags: c++, xcode, design-patterns, singleton

While trying do create a single instance of a class which will require global access and *modification* to it's name, I have some *syntax* related issue (I think) with my code in the implementation file.

When I compile, I get error on the return statement:

> non-const lvalue reference to type Single cannot bind to a value of unrelated type Single.

single.h

```
class Single{
public:
   std::string getSingleName();
   void updateSingleName(std::string name);
   void operator=(Single const&) = delete;
   Single(Single const&) = delete;
   static Single& getInstance(const std::string& name);

private:
    Single(std::string singleName);  
    std::string name;
};
```

Single.cpp

```
Single& Single::getInstance(const std::string& name){
     Single single(std::string name);
     return single;
}
```

Comment: `Single single(std::string name);` declares a function.

Comment: /OT Isn't _Singleton**s**_ in the title a contradiction per se?

Comment: I wish people would stop creating global variables/singletons :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `static` keyword for `single` in `getInstance`.  In order to return a reference you need a persistent object.  We do that with static like

```
Single& Single::getInstance(const std::string& name){
     static Single single(name); // get rid of the parameter type otherwise this is a function
     return single;
}
```

Do note that since `single` is now `static` it is only ever constructed once and any subsequent call to `getInstance` will return the same object as the previous call.

If you need to have multiple single objects that have different names then you are going to need something other than a singleton.  Possibly just getting rid of the copy constructor and making it movable will work for your use case.

Answer (score 4):

The combination of singleton and constructor arguments doesn't make any sense whatsoever. The point of a singleton is that (1) it exists at most once, and (2) anyone can get the singleton object at any time without having to check that someone has already created it - which means *everyone* would need to know the parameters, and obviously they would have to be the same, otherwise the singleton would behave differently depending on who created it.